# The purpose of the etymology tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, scope

I recently posted a question: [Signals and Slots: Etymology of "slots"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888747/signals-and-slots-etymology-of-slots).  This question was closed as off topic because it "wasn't a programming question."  However, as documented in the edit I made to the question, there is not only *an entire tag* devoted to etymology of programming terms, but several questions of similar nature tagged as such.

I'd like to either understand:

- Why my particular question is different from the other etymology questions cited, and thus off topic, or...
- ... whether we should remove a tag which is apparently targeted at a topic which is considered "off topic."

Comment: By the way, please don't use "QT" (QuickTime) when you want to talk about "Qt".

Comment: The capitalization matters?  **mutters under his breath**  I had strong enough opinions about that library before!  (Thanks for the advice, none the less)

Answer (score 18):

Thank you for bringing that tag to our attention! It's existence does not mean that questions about etymology of programming terms are on-topic.

In fact, all 22 posts with the tag are off-topic; I've removed it from all questions that used it, voting to close posts as I go. We call this process burnination (after the Strongbad character, Trogdor the Burninator).

I have now burninated the [etymology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag and all off-topic questions that used the tag have been closed.

[image: tag burninated]

♫♩ Burninating the countryside ♪♬ burninating the peasants ♫♩ burninating all the peoples ♬♪ in the thatch roofed cottages! ♬♩

*Wicked dueling guitar-solos*.

<del>It'll be gone completely with the next zombie tag cleanup run.</del> there is one [post under historic lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4137785) that'll keep it alive forever.

Comment: Wow, SO moves fast!  Thanks for clarifying for me.   Off hand, do you have any guess as to whether there is a StackExchange where this would be an on-topic question?  Its clearly not English or English Language and Usage. Programming, perhaps?

Comment: @CortAmmon: I don't know if it would be on topic on Programmers. I don't think it slots into any of the [permitted topics](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Actually, [it isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Betymology%5D+locked%3A1): [Why are variables “i” and “j” used for counters? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters)

Comment: @Deduplicator the post has a historical lock and as such doesn't show up on searches or on the tag page.

Comment: Yes. I guessed that was the reason you overlooked it. (There are a few other tags burned down to only locked posts.)

Comment: @CortAmmon I think this would probably be okay on English Language & Usage.  [See search for related questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=etymology+programming). Your question is a lot more technical than the examples already there, but I don't think you'd get shut down for asking, especially if you were careful to provide lots of references to help the language nerds figure out the programming meaning.

Comment: this question is full of holes.....Arrowed!!

Answer (score 14):

The fact that someone created a tag about something doesn't mean that that thing is on topic.

Etymology questions are not on topic on SO.