# Why is this question considered off-topic when it provides useful information not available elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, specific-question

This is about the recent classification of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246627/what-is-purpleeventcallback) question as "off-topic" and putting it on hold.

- This is a 2 year old question that has ~2k views, and 25 upvotes. I mention this because I'm taking that as indicative of the fact that at least 25 SO users found it helpful.
- I remember when I'd first asked the question, a moderator had instantly put it on hold because of the pseudo-poetry that I'd used in the text. I agree, it's a bit cheeky, but the question is still about a very valid problem. It's only after some context was added did the question live on.
- I think the current spurt of the people wanting to close this question are looking at it at too shallow an angle. I, as a programmer, like understanding the details of things, and often understanding the etymology behind things helps a lot in seeing how they fit into the bigger picture. I kept seeing an undocumented function in my stack traces, with no mention of it on the Internet. I came here and asked, and a friendly soul told me that it is the bridge between `CF` and `UIKit`. That's a nugget of information that many iOS programmers would appreciate. Now I can reason about the stack trace in a better manner, because I can see how the call traveled across different subsystems.
- One of the people wanting to close the question cited the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in a comment. IMO this question is a valid fit for the fourth bullet point - "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". I consider a "nagging doubt" to be a "problem".

See, I have no interest in keeping this open, for I got the answer I was looking for. I just think it is valuable information for posterity, and should not be removed because of some arbitrary conformance with guidelines.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I see no reason to close it for ligthhearted language. I see every reason to close it as not a real question. If you have an actual technical question, ask it. If you want to exercise your humor or poetic skills, find an appropriate site to do so. I don't see a question at all in what you posted. A new user who posts an attempt at poetry related to *How to add 1 + 1* with a graphic would be instantly downvoted to oblivion. I don't see a lot of difference here. Upvotes because a few people enjoyed your effort is not an indication of quality or usefulness.

Comment: @KenWhite The title looks like a question to me. Not really very important, but I don't see a good reason why it had to be closed. Sometimes it's interesting to know why something is called the way it is, and I see no harm in having the question around.

Comment: @Reto: OK. Some post, title *What does this mean?*, content some noise and an image, and it's good for you. Not so good for me. I'm OK that we agree to disagree. Standards for quality and value vary. Mine are clearly different than yours.

Comment: "I remember when I'd first asked the question, a moderator had instantly put it on hold because of the pseudo-poetry that I'd used in the text." You might have misremembered. I don't see any history of this ever happening, not even in a different account. The question you link to has only ever been put on hold once by the spurt of users you refer to.

Comment: @BoltClock I distinctly remember it, but yes, you're right, there do not seem to be history of it. FWIW, the first comment does say "I almost thought to close this **too**, but it actually seems to be real."

Comment: The wording of this question, especially the title, is presumptuous (it assumes that you know why it was closed), and not conducive to civil discussion. It might serve to edit it to not mislead with the title and to promote fair debate.

Comment: @Saposhiente You're right -- I assumed the close was being initiated because of the language. I've edited the title. Is that fine?

Comment: I noticed that the poem was edited out of the question and replaced with much more straight-forward prose. I did understand your poem and thought it was clever, but I think the new edit makes the question even more clear.

Comment: I got a "too localized vote" for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480340/billing-aliens-via-pos-printer-and-image-print. seems as if some people can't deal with humor.

Comment: A couple thoughts: 1. "Providing useful information" is not enough to meet the requirements for questions here. 2. Upvotes (especially on older questions) don't necessarily mean a question was *useful*, more that someone simply *liked* the question. 3. I definitely would have CV'd the question if I had run across it with the poetry. Now, however, it seems to be asking a more well-defined question. At first glance I'd still want to close it as Too Broad, or Off-Topic (need to show your code), but since it is iOS, there's a 50/50 chance that I might skip it in the queue/leave it for iOS users.

Comment: Sorry but I think the question - in its current form - should be closed. IMHO The thing that sets the Stack Exchange sites apart from every site out there is that the focus is on quality questions and answers. Your poetry detracts from the question (which was pretty flimsy to begin with). Let's make this a place for knowledge not personality.

Comment: @Basic: When you say "in its current form", do you mean the one where [the poetry was re-instated in the guise of a footnote](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12246627/5)? Because I don't see how it detracts from the question the way it is presented - it's way better than [having *just* poetry](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12246627/1), or [just the poetry and the image](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12246627/2).

Comment: @BoltClock It's orders of magnitude better than the previous versions, but to me it still seems superfluous. If you want to write poetry, post it on MySpace, why pollute SO with it? We don't allow Hi, Thanks, etc... I don't see how poetry is more relevant/useful?

Comment: @Basic: Ah, that clears it up. I see what you mean.

Comment: Whether the question was on-topic or not, _this_ post betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of how SO (and other topic-based communities) work. Just because something "provides useful information not found elsewhere" does not magically mean the thing belongs here. Similarly, just because you think it would be "valuable for posterity" doesn't mean we should throw away our "arbitrary guidelines" and accept the post with a sort of "honourary on-topic" status. Those "arbitrary guidelines" are _not_ "arbitrary": they are the unpinning of this community and the reason it thrives with high quality.

Comment: _"See, I have no interest in keeping this open, for I got the answer I was looking for."_ This is a similar misconception/misunderstanding. The question was never just for you. Every question here is for _everyone_. A decent member of this community will have an innate desire for a question to live on if it's valuable, because they will want others to benefit from it. Declaring that you don't care any more because _you_ got your problem solved really says a lot about your attitude. :(

Answer (score 38):

Note that the question originally had an [etymology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag which was the subject of [a recent burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287541/the-purpose-of-the-etymology-tag), which is what led to its recent closure. I don't dispute that etymology questions are off-topic, however I am assessing the topicality of this question *absent* the tag, now that it has been removed. Personally I think the removal of the tag alone changes the meaning of the question quite significantly.

---

The poetic language doesn't seem relevant here, since the reason given by the users who voted to close is:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Except, I don't see how this isn't a practical programming problem. Your question asks what this strangely-named entity in your stack trace is. People often demand that askers include stack traces in their debugging questions, so clearly they're supposed to be useful and we're supposed to pay attention to them. So I don't see what is so wrong in asking a question *about* a stack trace.

I reopened it.

Comment: For the first time, I'm sadly disappointed by your answer. I typically respect what you write, but this time it's wrong. There is no "question", and posting nonsense with an image of a stack trace does not make it a question. Stack traces are indeed useful, but not if they're not accompanied by a serious attempt at a question. I can produce a stack trace at random with a *strangely-named entity* when ever I want and accompany it with some nonsense text - does that meet the standards for you? (Please say yes - in 10 minutes I can produce a flood.)

Comment: @Ken White: There is a question in the title, and the text isn't entirely nonsensical as it clearly relates to the title. The only real *fluff* that I can see is that Hendrix reference, and the fact that the text isn't prosaic (which as I have mentioned now doesn't seem relevant here). If no one else is able to reproduce the same stack trace then the question is going to get closed as non-reproducible anyway. Based on the first comment on the question, and the answer that has since been given, it's clear that this is a legitimate stack trace and it's unlikely the image was doctored.

Comment: OK. I'll get started in the morning and post a few questions asking "What does <some strange name> in my stack trace mean?" followed by some semi-random noise and an image, and make sure I say "See this post on [meta]. BoltClock (a diamond moderator) says it's OK" and include a link. I have the capability of producing legitimate stack traces that haven't been doctored to support it. For the *some strange name*, does some variety of `SomeRandomNumber.ToString() + "BoltClock" + SomeRandomNumber.ToString()` work? Do I need to also include the name of a rock star/band?

Comment: @KenWhite I think you are missing some context, which is why from your viewpoint it looks like a "What does <some strange name> mean". I can assure you that is not the case. If you're doing iOS development, and if you pause your debugger on the main thread, this method will be more likely than not present in the stack trace. This is not some random function in some library or program, it is a function that comes as part of the SDK. And if you read the accepted answer to the question, it is a rather important function, providing the bridge between the old C based API and the newer iOS only one.

Comment: @Manav: You're right. I'm not aware of that context. What I am aware of is that, despite the context, questions should contain content. I can provide many methods that will be more likely than not present in a stack trace, most notably those contained in `ntdll.dll` on Windows. The functions there are rather important, but frequently do not actually pertain to the problem at hand. I can produce stack traces that include that library and some content at random, and it doesn't make it a question despite the name being commonly understood by Win32 developers.

Comment: @KenWhite If there are methods in `ntdll.dll` that could give information as to which OS subsystem did a stack trace originate in, _and_ those methods are not documented by Microsoft, then I'd say that SO questions that shed some light on them would prove useful to an odd fellow here and there once in a while. The question under consideration is the only reference on the Internet where the significance of this function can be understood by someone who does not have access to Apple's private source code. I know relativity and all, but does having that info on SO not sound useful to you? :)

Comment: @Manav: Certainly it sounds useful. Why would you taint that usefulness by trying to entertain in the process? If your intent is to educate, do so. If your intent is to show your wit instead, there are other sites.  There are dozens of things that can result in a stack trace showing *ntdll.dll*; they're typically irrelevant to the issue at hand. Familiarity with seeing something being present when you pause in a debugger does not constitute a reason for not providing details in your question itself.

Comment: My intent was not to show my wit. I thought folks won't mind a bit of banter on SO as it is just an un-official forum for people to help each other out. If everyone here seems to be offended by some frivolity, you guys go ahead and edit the question text to remove the "entertainment" component - I have no problems with that at all. All I wish is that the question not be closed because the accepted answer is useful indeed.

Comment: +1 I agree with BoltClock's decision for all reasons given. "What is `AnUnrecognizedEntity`?" is a perfectly reasonable question. The question itself could have been worded better (I liked it, but the core cause of complaints is more likely that it doesn't really look like the question showed any research effort, and also may rub some the wrong way) but that doesn't *really* matter, and at least it's not offensive or ranty. The thing is, it's hard for some to take a question seriously when it doesn't take itself seriously, and many people don't want to put effort into what looks like a joke.

Comment: @Jason C: The irony is that it probably takes conscious effort to make a question sound poetic on a site where technical prose is the norm ;)

Comment: @Manav: Well, I was the second-to-last close-voter there. My sincere apology for not taking longer pondering that question and seeing that *removing the bad tag* transformed it into a good question.

Comment: @KenWhite Your threat of "If this is permitted, I too will post questions that are unusual but potentially useful and interesting *and you won't be able to stop me*" is remarkably non-frightening. By all means, do so!

Comment: @MarkAmery: I think everyone reading it knows I had no intention of doing so. I was simply making a point. As my objection was because I don't agree the content should be kept, it's hardly likely I'd post more content that shouldn't be here; I would have thought that needed no explanation. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, and hey, we can have fun can't we? The edit is an improvement.

Comment: @superluminary The problem about "having fun" is that people have different sense of humor, and place the boundaries between "fun", "frivolity", "nonsense" and "harmful noise" differently. This is much more relative than judging technical usefulness of a question. Also, the latter is measured by votes, and adding another degree of freedom (is the post fun enough or too much) clouds this judgment.

Comment: @BartoszKP - Your points are valid and taken. The initial question does appear frivolous and noisy. On the other hand, humour used well can enhance a communication and we should refrain from automatically stripping it out. Humour is a difficult skill that I have never mastered, but which I respect in others.